# Flutter ~ ChangeNotifier is disposed too early (A * was used after being disposed)

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter app that successfully uses change notifiers. Except, sometimes a ChangeNotifier gets disposed while it is still in use, and the next time it calls `notifyListeners()`, the following error occurs:

```
E/flutter (24512): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: A StartupViewController was used after being disposed.
E/flutter (24512): Once you have called dispose() on a StartupViewController, it can no longer be used.
E/flutter (24512): #0      ChangeNotifier.debugAssertNotDisposed.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:157:9)
E/flutter (24512): #1      ChangeNotifier.debugAssertNotDisposed (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:164:6)
E/flutter (24512): #2      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:360:27)
E/flutter (24512): #3      StartupViewController._performLocalAuthAndAutoLoginIfEnabled (package:my_app/startup/startup_view_controller.dart:98:5)
E/flutter (24512): #4      StartupViewController._checkConnectionAndContinue (package:my_app/startup/startup_view_controller.dart:85:7)
```

Here's how the top lines of the view look:

```dart
class StartupView extends StatelessWidget {
  const StartupView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => StartupViewController(),
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          final displayType =
              context.watch<StartupViewController>().displayType;
          if (displayType.isRefreshState) {
            return _buildRefreshButtonWithText(displayType.message, context);
          } else {
            return ProgressSpinnerOverlay(text: displayType.message);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
[...]
```

And the `StartupViewController extends ChangeNotifier`.

Now, what happens is that on startup, the controller checks for internet connectivity and if a certain server can be reached. If yes, it proceeds to a login view, and if not, it displays a corresponding message and a retry-button. And while a connectivity check is in progress, it displays a loading spinner with a message, so far the theory.

However, what sometimes happens is that while the Controller awaits the response from the server, the Flutter framework calls the `dispose()`-Method of the Controller, and then this error happens.

Does anyone know why this happens and what I can do against that?